# Concatenate SQL in C# with order by

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbcommand

I have this code I would like to write `ORDER BY DESC` but I don't know how to 
can some one please help

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE [id] = " + Session_ID, conn2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM users 
  WHERE [id] = " + Session_ID + " ORDER BY ID DESC", conn2);
```

Though above will work it has serious flaw. One can simply do SQL Injection in above SQL Query so it is highly recommended to use parametrized query to prevent SQL Injection as suggested by @S.Akbari

Comment: don't encourge string concatenation because it's prone to sql injection.

Comment: A String.Format would've been nice, but you do answer the core of OP's question so +1.

Comment: That was how he was doing and not intended for SQL injection.

Comment: @Nino: Completely agree, but these considerations are for the OP to make; his question was not about preventing SQL injection. I do think a String.Format is warranted here, but this is again not the core of OP's question, it's simply an auxiliary improvement.

Comment: @Flater, no, that is completely wrong approach. Many users, including OP will accept and use first answer that solves their problem and, by doing so, they will learn the lazy and wrong way to code. Answer should be good and complete, not just quick and dirty one- liner written in a hurry to get +15 reputation

Comment: @Flater - if you think `String.Format` is the equivalent of parameterization, you're just demonstrating how much more effort needs to be put into *educating* people about risks. Encouraging someone to engage in risky behaviour *because they don't currently know better* is not a responsible way for adults to act.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I did not claim `String.Format` to be better than parametrization. I said that parametrization (or, more accurately, preventing SQL injection), while relevant in OP's code example, **is not the core issue of his current problem**. OP was asking about *string concatenation*. In that scope, a `String.Format` seemed relevant. If your answer is offtopic to the question that is asked (from OP's point of view), he will never accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: And if someone is asking how best to adjust their glasses using a sledge hammer, do you offer advice on the best grip and swing techniques or tell them *they're doing something wrong* and offer more sensible alternatives?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Questions need to be answered in a way that they can make sense for future readers too. Just because many improvements should be made to that code, does not mean that **this question** needs to perform all of them. Why aren't we suggesting the use of Entity Framework then? It's generally considered better than direct control over SQL. Suggesting EF is the same principle as suggesting parametrization. They are objectively safer, but both are out of scope for OP's original problem.

Comment: Answers like that are the reason why we still have so many silly vulnerabilities in 2017.

Comment: @Nino: I agree that the prevention of SQL injection is a good thing. If Bhuban wanted to, he could have made a sidenote pulling OP's attention to this. However, it would be wrong to say Bhuban's answer is **incorrect**. It correctly addresses the question OP is asking. It simply omits further optimizations that, while objectively better, are out of scope for the question that was asked.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma: Lazy or outdated developers is why we have silly vulnerabilities. StackOverflow's answers are not directly responsible for the code that someone chooses to deliver professionally, **no matter how much SO can insist that something is correct**.

Comment: @Flater actually it is incorrect, for the problem at hand. Concatenation invariably leads to conversion errors. If there is a proper, easier solution to , the dirty patch is wrong

Comment: @Flater on the contrary. Hackers do scan SO because they know bad answers end up in production code. There are *hundreds* of correct duplicate answers anyway.

Comment: Considering all your points; solution I have provided has flaw but how could you suggest and hope that questioner will write parametrized command when he has issue with string concatenation. 

So it is best idea to give him what he wanted and tell him that was bad idea and then suggest what he should do now which I have done

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: For your first comment: I agree with you, and I am not saying you're wrong. But OP's question inherently states that he **will** be using strings for running SQL statements. We can't just tell him to completely uproot that. For your second comment, while I believe you that this happens, that does not make SO **responsible** for the mistakes that developers make!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: If the question is "I **will** be using a hammer to adjust my glasses, how to best do it?", My answer would be "If you must use a hammer, wrap a pillow around it and swing it slowly. But I would advise that you use your hands to adjust the glasses". Not "Use your fingers to adjust your glasses.", which is what you're suggesting. The goal is the same, but your suggested answer completely ignores the fact that OP **is using** concatenation for his SQL queries (for whatever reasons, including ones that OP cannot change himself).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you should be aware that this kind of codes are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid *SQL Injection*. Like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE [id] = ? " +
                                    "ORDER BY ID DESC", conn2);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@SessionID", Session_ID));
```

Comment: OLE DB doesn't support named parameters. You'd need to use `?` as the placeholder and ensure that parameters are added to the collection in the correct order.